# Difference between await and async and Task parallel library

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, c#-5.0

What is the difference between Task Parallel Library and await and async. What was the need to introduce await and async? I see TPL is part of C# 4.0 and await/async is part of C# 5.0 but apart from that what is the basic difference. What was the need to introduce this new keyword?

Comment: The key is about composing.

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/10/28/asynchrony-in-c-5-part-one.aspx

Comment: TPL was released at the same time as C# 4.0, but it's not part of it, it's part of .Net 4.0. There is nothing in C# 4.0 related to TPL.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The Task Parallel Library was designed for [parallel programming](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff963553.aspx) - when you have a lot of work to do and want to split up that work among multiple threads so you can use all the CPU cores. TPL is best suited for CPU-intensive work.

Async and await are for [asynchronous programming](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj152938.aspx) - when you have an operation (or many operations) that will complete in the future, and you want to do other things in the meantime. Async is best suited for I/O-bound work.

There is some overlap. For example, you can treat a parallel computation as an asynchronous operation so it doesn't tie up your UI thread. Also, both the TPL and async/await make use of the `Task` type, though they use it in very different ways.